# Do Stormcast Eternals Rest or Sleep?

Tags: age-of-sigmar, stormcast-eternals

Games Workshop are calling for authors and I want to write an story about an expedition of Stormcast Eternals into the Realm of Death.

I want to write a campfire scene, however I'm not aware of any story where Stormcasts ever rest, eat or sleep.

Do the stormcasts rest or sleep or are they somehow magically imbued with unlimited energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the short story [*Lightning Golem*](https://www.blacklibrary.com/authors/nick-kyme/eshort-the-lightning-golem.html), a Stormcast Eternal called Issakian claims to have slept. There's no good reason to disbelieve him.

> **‘I hoped you would sleep,’** said Agrevaine, and slid up beside him.
> Her bare skin felt warm, welcoming. Issakian touched her hand with his then
> leaned over to softly kiss her fingers.
> **‘I did for a while,’** he said, and listened to the howl of the wind outside their
> tent. The leather creaked ominously; the ropes pulled but held. ‘But I am glad I
> can wake up to you.’

In the short story [Force of Personality](https://www.blacklibrary.com/authors/david-guymer/force-of-personality-eshort-2019.html), another Stormcast Eternal named Hamilcar tells us that he's still human-ish. This evidently includes eating and sleeping.

> The first forged of the Stormcast Eternals are in many ways more human
> than those who came after. We can laugh, enjoy mortal company, recall
> bits and pieces of our former lives. Perhaps this is something that
> the God-King would rather I not share, but I tell you here because,
> with that knowledge in mind, events in Nemisuvik might be taken as
> further evidence of my place in Azyr’s firmament of heroes. I was
> still human enough to know fear…
> ...
> ‘Perseverance and generosity,’ I said through gritted teeth, assuming a place by the hearthpot. **I would have one more bowl of broth, and then I would sleep on it.**
>
> **I woke to a string of calamitous booms,** sky-splitting, shivering the cut-out canoe-cots of the maorai hall in which I slept, rattling spare weapons in their racks.